# How to overlay global map on filled contour in R language

Tags: r, graphics, contour

I would like to plot some lat-lon data in a filled contour, and then overlay a map of the globe on top.  I am trying something like this:

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data,
plot.axes={axis(1);axis(2);map(projection='rectangular',parameters=0,add=T)}
)
```

The contour is plotted fine, and the map shows up, but only as a very tiny little black rectangle in a small area of the contour plot.  Of course, I want the map to stretch over the entire area of the filled contour plot.

I've also tried something like:

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data,
plot.axes={axis(1);axis(2);map(projection='rectangular',x=lons,y=lats,parameters=0,add=T)}
)
```

In this case, the map does not plot at all and I get an error message "nothing to draw: all regions out of bounds"
People apparently do this successfully all the time, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  BTW, I don't want to use the lattice package.  It will not work with the other stuff my group is doing.  Thanks.

Comment: For the benefit of others, this was answered here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/321207.html

Comment: Sorry, but that answer gives me a different but similar problem.  The map still does not fit on the filled contour region.

Comment: that is because you choose a different projection for the map, different to the one your data are in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. for anyone who cares, I have an answer.  Maybe not the best answer, but an answer.  The problem is that there are 2 common ways to represent latitude and longitude: degrees and radians.  There is a third common way to represent longitude: local time, i.e. time zone time generalized as floating point numbers.  And then, to make life more interesting, longitude in degrees is often given as -180 (east) to 180 (West) OR 0 to 360.

Now, when you try to display a map, R automatically picks the lat-lon units for the display based on the innards of the maps package.  If you are working in one set of units, but R wants to display the map in another set, you get trouble.  Another wrinkle is that different map projections want to be displayed with different units.  As I have discovered, the "default" projection likes degrees; it wants to be displayed in a plot rectangle with limits -180 to 180 in longitude, and -90 to 90 in latitude.  BUT, the "rectangular" projection, though it looks very much like the default projection, likes radians; it wants to be displayed in a rectangle stretching -pi to pi (longitude) and -pi/2 to pi/2 (latitude).  *These plot limits are not discussed at all in ?mapproject.*

So here's what you need to do:
1) Determine which map projection you want and then determine what limits it is plotted in:

```
> map(projection=foo,parameters=foo)
> par('usr')   # will return vector of plot limits
```

2) Know the units your own data is expressed in.  If you have just grabbed someone else's data set, you might be surprised here.

3) When you plot ...

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data)
```

if your "lons" and "lats" are in units consistent with the limits your projection expects, then you should be OK, and you should be able to simply add a map with

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data,
plot.axes={axis(1,...);axis(2,...);map(projection=foo,parameters=foo,add=T)})
```

But if your lons and lats are *not* what the projection needs, then you have a little more work to do.  You have to redefine the limits of your plot with a call to par().  This is what worked for me:

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data,
plot.axes={axis(1,...);axis(2,...);par(usr=c(-180,180,-90,90));
map(add=T)})
```

And when I needed the prime meridian at the left end of the plot (i,e, longitude everywhere increasing on the x axis from 0 to 360) I made two calls to par() and map():

```
filled.contour(lons, lats, glb.data,
plot.axes={axis(1,...);axis(2,...);
par(usr=c(0,360,-90,90));map(add=T);  #eastern hemisphere
par(usr=c(-360,0,-90,90));map(add=T)}   #western
)
```

There are some other wrinkles too.  (e.g. the 'rectangular' projection does not have limits of *precisely* -pi an +pi.)  But if what I have said so far makes sense, you will be able to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `image`?

```
image(lons, lats, glb.data)
library(maps)
map(add = TRUE)
```

Where did you get the idea to try to put `map()` in the `plot.axes` argument?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with image, but as I understand it, it doesn't give a color bar.  And it doesn't interpolate, so the colors come out looking "blocky".  I tried this and I get a different but related problem: the map appears, but runs off the edge of the window.  This got me thinking, though.  I can get an approximation to what I want by fiddling with par(usr).  There must be a better way, but it works after I fine tune it enough.  I got the idea because, AFAICT, "plot.axes" is the usual way to add level lines or coordinate lines to a filled contour.  I figured a map would work too.Thanks.

Comment: it does interpolate with useRaster = TRUE, filled.contour sets up its own coordinate system that overrides the base one, which is why the map is offset, use Duncan Murdoch's answer, or use sp::spplot or raster package