# Overlapping data contour on a map

Tags: r, maps, contour

I have gone through few tutorials and answers here in stackoverflow such as:
[Overlap image plot on a Google Map background in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886494/overlap-image-plot-on-a-google-map-background-in-r) or 
[Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid) or [Geographical heat map of a custom property in R with ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847188/geographical-heat-map-of-a-custom-property-in-r-with-ggmap) or [How to overlay global map on filled contour in R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891908/how-to-overlay-global-map-on-filled-contour-in-r-language) or https://blog.dominodatalab.com/geographic-visualization-with-rs-ggmaps/
They either don't serve my purpose or consider the density of the data to create the image.

I am looking for a way to plot contour on a map of a certain data, and would expect the image to look something like this:
[image]

or something like this taken from https://dsparks.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/mapping-public-opinion-a-tutorial/:[image]

I have a data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tE0hxVftprlPDq_7Zgox2MaFDvtBfCbV0zVWTDyQomI/edit?usp=sharing) that gives a contour plot like this in `plot_ly` but i want this over the map given by latitudes and longitudes.

[image]

Please guide me on how this can be done. Any links to potential answers or codes would be helpful.

Comment: The problem with this data is that you have a symmetrical points or grids. Besides in your desired map, Lat is in the 'x' axis while it have to be in the Y axis.

Comment: With Lat in y-axis can this be possible?

Comment: Nope. Because you have points. And you need polygons to do a map like this. Try to convert your data to a shapefile. Maybe this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-February/007625.html) could help

Comment: Would you elaborate on how I can get polygons? a sample would do.

Comment: Lets say I can convert the data into a SpatialPolygon object then?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did some digging and figured that to plot the data -which in this case are point values randomly distributed across the Latitude and Longitude, one has to make it continuous instead of the discreetly distributed one. To do this I interpolated the data to fill in the gaps, this method is given in [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid) and then take it from there. Now the interpolation here is done using a linear regression, one can use other methods such as IDW, Kriging, Nearest Neighbourhood etc for which R-packages are easily available. These methods are widely used in climatology and topographic analysis. To read more about interpolation methods see [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1345F0DEAE54FF9B2963686B679CCC89?doi=10.1.1.621.2455&rep=rep1&type=pdf).